# Segregating Controls to each type using Lambda Expression c#

Tags: c#, lambda, logic

Can something enlighten me, I just wonder if there's easy and efficient way in handling different types of [Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls(v=vs.110).aspx)

Here's the scenario:

I have a [Panel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx) Control. inside on my panel there's plenty amount of controls like,
[Textbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372076(v=vs.85).aspx), [Combobox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367871(v=vs.85).aspx), and [DateEdit](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsDateEdittopic).

Now i wanted to gather all the control using lambda expression so i did in this way..

```
 panel.Controls.Cast<Control>()
            .Where(c => c is TextBox || c is DateEdit || c is ComboBox)
            .OrderBy(or => or.Name)
            .Where(t => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Text))
```

the result was success, i have fetch the controls where the types are Textbox, dateedit, and combobox then iv'e sorted in asc by control name, then filtered by control has value...

Now here's my question is there any easy possible way to segregate the types of control?  coz i wanted to put all data value into [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) witch the object is

```
public class Child
{
    public TextBox ChildName { get; set; }
    public ComboBox ChildType { get; set; }
    public DateEdit ChildBirth { get; set; }
}
```

therefore i can easily manage the data value of each control.

Thanks

Comment: What is the relationship that keeps together 3 controls and make them an object of type Child? I mean, if you have 2 TextBoxes, 2 Comboboxes, 2 DateEdit (?) how do you define the rule that put the 3 controls in an element of type Chiild and the next 3 in another element?

Comment: @Steve here's what it looks like https://i.imgsafe.org/31df1ab453.png

i got plenty controls and im looking for the easiest way to get all their value so that i can just loop it to insert in database.. 

their name was sequential like txtName1, txtName2, cbType1, cbType2, Date1, Date2 so on and so forth...

Comment: using windows form?

Comment: @UmairAnwaar absolutely

Comment: I often add control to a List<object> like List<TextBox>().  It makes it very easy to enumerate.  In you case I would use List<Child>().

Comment: @jdweng i get it ill try your this one, :) i hope these could not take 20lines of code